# Plotting a DateListPlot and a CandleStickChart together

Tags: plotting, finance

I'm trying to plot a DateListPlot and a CandleStickChart together.

Initially I was trying to add a FinancialIndicator by spelunking TradingChart, but it's quite complex, I think I could manage to do it, but it would take some time.

Here's a basic example that doesn't work

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2009, 5, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}}];
y = CandlestickChart@data;
x = DateListPlot[{{{2009, 5, 1}, 1}, {{2010, 4, 30}, 40}}];
Show[{x, y}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying issue is that `CandlestickChart` is not using date values on its x-axis.  With `First@y` we can see that the x-axis values are index positions (and slight offsets) of the values in `data`.

You can get the benefits of `Show` (e.g. retain interactivity) by listing the `CandlestickChart` first and using `ListPlot` with values indexed to their respective dates in `data`.

For example, if `listPoints` contains the dates and values you want for your `ListPlot`.

```
listPoints = {{{2009, 5, 1}, 85}, {{2009, 9, 1}, 100}, {{2010, 4, 1}, 
   110}, {{2010, 4, 30}, 120}};
```

Then a `ListPlot` on the same scale as the `CandlestickChart` can be made by the following.

```
x1 = ListPlot[
      {First@PositionIndex[data[[All, 1]]][First@#],Last@#} & /@ listPoints, 
      Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then these can be combined with `Show`.

```
Show[y, x1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The show has all ticks and grid lines of the `CandlestickChart` since it was listed first and keeps the interactivity of all the charts (here only the candle stick chart has interactivity).

The above assumes that the dates in `listPoints` are in `data`. If not then you will need to add some interpolation to assign an x-value between the two `data`  date indices that the `listPoints` date falls in between.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
x =
 DateListPlot[{{{2009, 5, 1}, 1}, {{2010, 4, 30}, 40}}, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> 20];

y = CandlestickChart[data, ImagePadding -> 20];

Overlay[{x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, simple and effective !