# How to add a line to a CandlestickChart

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts, finance

I seek to add a horizontal line to a [CandlestickChart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CandlestickChart.html).

This question is similar to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102880/plotting-a-datelistplot-and-a-candlestickchart-together)

Here's the code:

```
csc = CandlestickChart[{"SP500", {{2018, 9, 20}, Today}}]
line = {{{2018, 10, 02}, 3025}, {{2018, 10, 26}, 3025}};
dlp = DateListPlot[line];
Overlay[{Show[{csc}, Axes -> True, DataRange -> {{2018, 9, 20}, Today}, PlotRange -> {2600, 3050}], 
         Show[{dlp}, Axes -> True, DataRange -> {{2018, 9, 20}, Today}, PlotRange -> {2600, 3050}]}]
```

There are a couple of issues. The graphics don't overlay precisely. And the line extends beyond the specified endpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = FinancialData["SP500", "OHLC",{{2018, 9, 20}, Today}];
line = {{{2018, 10, 02}, 3025}, {{2018, 10, 26}, 3025}};
line[[All, 1]] = Flatten@Nearest[data[[All, 1]] -> "Index", line[[All, 1]]];
CandlestickChart[data, PlotRange -> {All, {2600, 3050}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[line]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]